# Dataflow - Write to BigQuery - Tuple to Dictionary

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to perform the last transformation on my beam pipeline (using Google Dataflow as a runner but to test DirectRunner) and am struggling to understand how to change my rows from tuples to dictionaries.  I've tried doing a ParDo function with a custom class that converts tuple to dict.  The debug I added to the TupToDict function outputs the following so I think it should work?  Any help is appreciated... I'm going bald from ripping my hair out :).  To test I've changed to directrunner.  I've also 'xxxxx' out project info, etc.

**Output from TupToDict function.**

```
(u'A3VZVMI3JWCFPD', 5.0)
product_id= A3VZVMI3JWCFPD
avg_rating= 5.0
{'avg_rating': 5.0, 'product_id': u'A3VZVMI3JWCFPD'}
```

**output in string.txt from directrunner**

```
avg_rating
product_id
avg_rating
product_id
avg_rating
product_id
```

````
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    import sys
    import logging

    PROJECT='xxxx'
    BUCKET='xxxxxxxx'
    schema = 'product_id:STRING,avg_rating:FLOAT'

    class Split(beam.DoFn):
    #
    # This class returns each row as a dictionary
    #
        def process(self, element):
            user_id, product_id, rating = element.split(",")

            return [{
                'user_id': user_id,
                'product_id': product_id,
                'rating': float(rating),
            }]


    class CollectProductID(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            #returns a list of tuples containing product_id and rating
            result = [(element['product_id'], element['rating'])]
            return result


    class TupToDict(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
                print element
            print "product_id=",element[0]
            print "avg_rating=",element[1]
            di = {'product_id': element[0],'avg_rating': element[1]}
            print di
            return di


    def run():
       argv = [
          '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
          '--staging_location=gs://{0}/'.format(BUCKET),
          '--temp_location=gs://{0}/'.format(BUCKET),
          #'--runner=DataflowRunner'
          '--runner=DirectRunner'
       ]

       p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)

       (p
          | 'ReadFromGCS' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText('gs://{0}/xxxxx_10k.csv'.format(BUCKET))
          # Next Transform splits the read PCollection CSV into rows of dictionaries
          | 'ParseCSV' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
          # Next Transform breaks each row into a tuple and the following one groups by product ID's
          | 'CombineProduct' >> beam.ParDo(CollectProductID())
          | 'Grouping Product IDs' >> beam.GroupByKey()
          # Next Transform averages the ratings per product_id
          | 'Calculating Average' >> beam.CombineValues(beam.combiners.MeanCombineFn())
          # Next Transform converts to a dictionary
          | 'Convert To Dict' >> beam.ParDo(TupToDict())
          # Next Transform maps keys to BigQuery Columns
          #| 'Map to BQ COL' >> beam.Map(lamda line: dict(record=line))
          # Next two are to toggle local writing to to BQ
          | 'Write to file' >> beam.io.WriteToText('strings', file_name_suffix='.txt')
          #| 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:xxxxxx.ecomm_product_ratings_avg'.format(PROJECT), schema=schema))

       p.run()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
           logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
           run()```
````

Comment: I know nothing about beam, but your other Process functions are all returning a list containing the results. Might you perhaps need to `return [di]` in `TupToDict` as well?

Comment: You sir, are correct.   Thanks so much! It workred!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tzaman is a hero.  I needed to add [] to my TupToDict function to return the actual dictionary.

I changed it over to dataflow as a runner and it went into BQ fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try yielding your dictionary instead of returning

```
def process(self, element):
    print (element)
    print("product_id=",element[0])
    print("avg_rating=",element[1])
    di = {'product_id': element[0],'avg_rating': element[1]}
    print (di)
    yield di
```

A process function must return an iterable meaning that if you return a dict it will iterate over the dict which is why it will only store the keys in your output. If you yield your dict it will return a generator containing your dicts as elements.